# Display different variation of products

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I don't have a correct question title but i will try to ask my question as clearly i can.

```
product_table
    ID | product_code | product name | company_id 
    1  |  12345       | beer cake    |343434defee
    2  |  12346       | vodka cake   |343434deereee

product_table
       Product_code |Quantity | price | weight 
       12345        |  34     |345    |0.5 
       12345        |  343    |600    |1.0 
       12345        |  4      |845    |1.5 
       12346        |  341    |345    |0.5
```

This is how my two tables at the Db side looks like,`product_code` in the second table is the foreign key while `product_code` and `weight` are the composite keys for the table two.

In the first table , `ID` is the primary key  while `product_code` is unique.

Mysql is used at the Db side , Php at the server side and JS/Jquery is used at the client side.

Suppose, i have to display these products on the product landing page.

[image]

It has two weight variants `0.5` `1.0` and there could be more.Depending on the weight for the corresponding product present.

What i was trying to achieve was to somehow display these products on the landing page and when the person clicks on the specific weight, the price and the quantity to the corresponding weight should show up.

Consider, the first three rows of second table
Three separate buttons for these should come up and further if any one of them has the quantity zero, it should be disabled or that weight shouldn't come up.

Secondly, if all of the weights have quantity as zero , display sold out image.

How can i achieve this with JS/JQUERY/HTML/PHP?

Regards,
BOTJr.
Thanks.

Comment: dear friend i'm happy that i succeeded to help you, if you can just mark it with right answer :)

Answer (score 1):

### Database:

```html
CREATE TABLE `product_table` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_code` INT NULL,
  `product_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `company_id` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

  CREATE TABLE `product_table_price` (
  `product_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 


INSERT INTO `product_table` (`product_code`, `product_name`, `company_id`) VALUES ('12345', 'beer cake', '343434defee');
INSERT INTO `product_table` (`product_code`, `product_name`, `company_id`) VALUES ('12346', 'vodka cake', '343434deereee');


INSERT INTO `product_table_price` (`product_code`, `quantity`, `price`, `weight`) VALUES ('12345', '34', '345', '0.5');
INSERT INTO `product_table_price` (`product_code`, `quantity`, `price`, `weight`) VALUES ('12345', '343', '600', '1.0');
INSERT INTO `product_table_price` (`product_code`, `quantity`, `price`, `weight`) VALUES ('12345', '4', '845', '1.5');
INSERT INTO `product_table_price` (`product_code`, `quantity`, `price`, `weight`) VALUES ('12346', '341', '345', '0.5');
```

### db.php the connection to the database:

```html
<?php

$username = 'kmoshe';
$password = 'password';
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'test';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$username, $password
    ,
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ));
```

### index.php:

```html
<?php
require_once './db.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>StackOverFlow</title>

    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="products">
    <?php
    // In this part of the code i'm building div's that have tag attributes that i've created with the
    // row-id, product-code, that those attributes contain the values from the db
    // i have given a class name of item, and i'm going to catch the click event on this with JQuery
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product_table";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){ ?>
        <div class="item" row-id="<?=$row['id'];?>" product-code="<?=$row['product_code']?>"><span><?= $row['product_name'];?></span></div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

### app.js:

```js
$(document).ready( function(){

        $(document).on('click','.item', function(e) {

            let pressedRowID =$(this).attr('row-id');
            let pressedProductCode =$(this).attr('product-code');
            let fd = new FormData();

            fd.append('id', pressedRowID);
            fd.append('product_code', pressedProductCode);

            console.log(pressedRowID, pressedProductCode);

            // In this part of the code according to the pressed product-code, we are going to fetch
            // the rows from the second table, the php will return a json structure that contains the 3 rows
            // or more with the  price and the quantity.

            $.ajax({
                url: "get_buttons.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,

                complete: function (results) {
                    try {
                        let str = JSON.parse(results.responseText);
                         updateDOM(str);
                         console.log(str)
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error(e.message);
                    }
                },
            });


        }) ;



     updateDOM = (buttons) => {

         let disabled;
         let weight;
         let buttons_dom='';
         let buttons_container = $('#buttons-container');

         for (let property in buttons) {

             if(buttons[property].hasOwnProperty('quantity') && parseInt(buttons[property]['quantity']) !== 0) {
                 disabled = '';
             } else if (buttons[property].hasOwnProperty('quantity') && parseInt(buttons[property]['quantity']) === 0) {
                 disabled = 'disabled';
             }

             if(buttons[property].hasOwnProperty('weight')) {
                 weight = buttons[property]['weight'];
             }
             buttons_dom += `<button ${disabled}>${weight}</button>`;
         }



         buttons_container.html ('');
         buttons_container.append(buttons_dom);


    };



});
```

### get_buttons.php:

```html
<?php
require_once 'db.php';

$product_code = $_REQUEST['product_code'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM product_table_price where product_code=$product_code";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$product_items = [];
$product_item = [];

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $product_item['product_code'] = $row['product_code'];
    $product_item['quantity'] = $row['quantity'];
    $product_item['price'] = $row['price'];
    $product_item['weight'] = $row['weight'];
    $product_item['id'] = $row['id'];
    array_push($product_items, $product_item);
}

echo json_encode($product_items);
```